# How to create a Popsicle Material?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

Looking to make a material that looks like this popsicle with a subtle bumpy texture, a slight sheen, and a frosty/matte look, thanks for any help!

[image: Red white and blue firecracker popsicle]

Comment: You should post what you have already attempted, and elaborate on any issues you have run into. StackExchange is meant to be a "Help me figure out what's wrong" forum, not a "Please do it for me" forum.

Comment: I see the trick here as being how to make the three dimensional inner ice crystal look. I feel this is, however, a question more for the blender subreddit, where how-to-from-scratch questions can more easily receive answers and discussion. You can, of course, always check the blender manual on the subject, and I would recommend Material Shader Nodes and possibly Particles as a starting point: docs.blender.org

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - I'll try to give a full writeup when I have more time - basically something like this brings out the "works". The bumpy surface is achieved by layers of different size *Noise Textures* and *Voronoi Textures* (also warped by some noise using a vector math node). Once the "mix" is complete, it's just a matter of finding the correct specific values to input to the sockets (exemplified by ColorRamps). The Color itself is the easy part - an "ice pop" calls for all the complex shader functions - *transmission* to let the light through like ice - *subsurface scattering* to make the colors "bleed" through the ice - *clearcoat* for the shiny, yet also matte surface, etc... - like I said, the works.

Until I am able to fully break down the graph, I'll upload an example .blend file for anyone who wants to play with it. Obviously, it could be improved, but I think I covered enough in the graph that any "fine tuning" that is necessary will also be obvious enough about how to accomplish it.

[image: Pop1]

[image: Pop2]

File is here - [image]